# Port Forwarding - Two Gateways Routing - One Network Card

Tags: port-forwarding, gateway

I have two ports forwarding to my local machine from two different gateways (adsl routers). However, port forwarding only seems to work with whatever is set as my default gateway. Presumably, because whatever comes from the non-default gateway gets forced down the default gateway and the connection is essentially dropped (from Client's POV).

I can ONLY change my workstation (Windows 7) config, though whatever I like thereon (OS/software). I only have ONE network adapter. I was trying to set up something on my workstation to force it to respond via the same gateway a requests comes from.

I have assigned two IPs to my Network Card. Each router forwards to a different IP. I don't know how to set up these policy-based routes on a Windows machine. This seems to be relatively simple on Linux machines, using iptables, but I can't find how to do it on a windows machine.

Please can someone tell me how, or come up with alternatives based within my limitations (only workstation changes)?

Comment: What OS on the client?  Search for 'policy-based-routing'.  If OS=Windows, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to assign the workstation machine two fixed local IPs. Then you must configure one gateway to forward to one IP and the other gateway to forward to the other. Then you must setup policy-based routing on the workstation so that the next hop on the replies is determined by the local source address.

Comment: I have assigned two IPs to my Network Card. Each router forwards to a different IP. I don't know how to set up these policy-based routes on a Windows machine (edited Question to include my OS). This seems to be relatively simple on Linux machines, using iptables, but I can't find how to do it on a windows machine.

Comment: I'd just put a Linux machine in front of the workstation. It can be a cheap little SoHo router running OpenWRT or the like.